# middleware.js in nextjs doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const middleware = (request) => {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === request.nextUrl.pathname.toLocaleLowerCase())
    return NextResponse.next()
  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `${request.nextUrl.origin}${request.nextUrl.pathname.toLocaleLowerCase()}`
  )
}

export { middleware }
```

(Next v.12.2.3)
**No matter what I code, pages/middleware.js seems not running at all!**

I wanna redirect uppercase urls to lowercase urls.

what should I do?

Comment: Did you attach the middleware to your router?

Comment: @AsadAwadia there was no such thing in doc of next!

Comment: @AsadAwadia can you elaborate - is this actually required in Next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation says](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware):

> Create a `middleware.ts` (or `.js`) file at the same level as your `pages` directory

So it shouldn't be inside `pages/`, but *in the same directory as `pages/`*.

Comment: yeah, you're right :) the statement on nextjs.org was a bit confusing though. thank you